# Website with a Increasing size background

Tags: css, background

I am new to web development. I designed an image and i want this image as background It is a curved one. When I put matter it should increase the background accordingly.

Please help me in this regard

Thanks

TeeKeyBee
[image]

Comment: CSS is not an image description language.

Comment: to create irregular shape you may need to use CSS3. and using some pseudo class..

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/  here are a list of shapes you can make with css

Answer (score 0):

You can use `border-radius` for some simple oval shaped divs, by combining multiple divs and multiple classes you can achieve something like that, but its quite hard.